# Laravel elixir on linux

Tags: linux, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using Linux Mint and I'm trying to run compile sass file.
I have installed npm and node. But when I run `gulp` , it doesn't compile and it doesn't make css file in `public` directory.
When I run it, itdoesn't show any error or anything.

How should I compile sass file in Laravel 5.2? Thanks!

Edited: This is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Gulpfile.js is:

```html
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

My app.scss file is:

```html
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

li {
  color: red;
}

Updated: When I ran again `npm install` there is this error:
```

[image: screen-shot]

Then I ran:
`whereis nodejs` and output was:

`nodejs: /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/bin/X11/nodejs /usr/include/nodejs /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz`

and to link nodejs to node symlink I ran:
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

But when I run `gulp` still the same.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of the console after running gulp. Also have you ran npm install before running gulp?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Post your gulpfile.js

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Have you got anything in your app.scss file for it to compile?

Comment: Yes, I have, I posted it. I've run gulp on windows and it has worked. Now, when I try it on linux, it's not. Maybe I haven't something installed.

Comment: Weird. I'm guessing if you were missing something you'd see some errors in the console. Unsure how to debug such an issue, sorry! My last guess is it could be do to with file paths perhaps search your project folder for the compiled file or recompiling with explicit path? Also, it may be worth stating in your question what Linux distro you're using and if you're running gulp on your os or on in a vm like homestead.

Comment: Oh and you could always make an issue here to get help: https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint. I'll post question there and try again..

Comment: All the best. Hope you find your answer

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies using the command `npm install` in the directory `/var/www/html/Laravel` so that you would have a directory named `node_modules`?

Comment: I updated my question. There are errors when I ran it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try specifying the css file like in the code below?

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
        .version('css/app.css');
});
```

I hope this solves your problem!